# Jupyter notebook slide output

Tags: python, command-line, jupyter-notebook, output, command-prompt

I want to output the jupyter notebook with following command in the anaconda prompt.

```
jupyter nbconvert pythonjupyter.ipynb --to slides -- post serve
--SlidesExporter.reveal_theme=serif 
--SlidesExporter.reveal_scroll=True 
--SlidesExporter.reveal_transition=none
```

However, it returned:

```
'--SlidesExporter.reveal_theme' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
'--SlidesExporter.reveal_scroll' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
'--SlidesExporter.reveal_transition' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Any solution? It seems that I need to set the path but have no idea where is my path....

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.
Pass them together:

```
jupyter nbconvert pythonjupyter.ipynb --to slides --post serve --SlidesExporter.reveal_scroll=True
```